# Django Rest API end point 405 error in IE browser

Tags: python, internet-explorer

Django Rest Framework API endpoint not listing via Proxy enabled mode

I'm using Django rest framework for developing API service for my project.

I'm using normal APIView in the application and it is hosted in the IIS server using FastCGI method.

Normally it has working fine in all the browsers. Once I enable proxy in my server, it's not able access from the IE browser only. But it can able to access in the Chrome browser. So, in IE it throws the 405 error after enabling the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

The 405 Method Not Allowed is an HTTP response status code indicating that the specified request HTTP method was received and recognized by the server, but the server has rejected that particular method for the requested resource.

You can try to troubleshoot this issue from client and server side.

**Troubleshooting on the Client-Side:**

(1) Check the Requested URL

(2) Debugging Common Platforms

(3) Rollback Recent Upgrades

(4) Uninstall New Extensions, Modules, or Plugins

(5) Check for Unexpected Database Changes

**Troubleshooting on the Server-Side:**

(1) Confirm Your Server Configuration

(2) Look Through the Logs

(3) Debug Your Application Code or Scripts

For more detailed information you can refer links below.

(1) [405 Method Not Allowed: What It Is and How to Fix It](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/405-method-not-allowed)

(2) [HTTP Error “405 Method Not Allowed”: How to solve the problem](https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/error-405-method-not-allowed-explanation-and-solutions/)

Comment: i have added "_" in my API URL endpoints. After removing the "_" it starts working in IE. Thanks for your replay.